# JButton Not working in My java Code

Tags: java, mouseevent, jbutton, mouselistener

My Mouse click not working. I tried it with diffrent types. 
Here is the Button Class and Display Class. There are no error in my project. But mouse not working. Here, i implemented mouse listener interface in button class. then i created a button class object, then added ation listener to that button object.

> Button Class:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;

public class Button extends JButton implements MouseListener{

    private boolean click = false;

    public Button(String text) {
        super(text);
        setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 30));
        setText(text);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        click = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {

    }

    public boolean getClick() {
        return click;
    }

}
```

> Display Class:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.js.CandyThief.CustomButton.Button;


public class Display{

    private String title;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    private JFrame frame;

    Button btnPlay = new Button("Play");
    Button btnHelp = new Button("Help");
    Button btnCredits = new Button("Credits");
    public Button btnExit = new Button("Exit");


    public Display(String title, int width, int height){
        super();
        this.title = title;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;

        createDisplay();
    }
    private void createDisplay(){
        frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.setSize(width, height);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnPlay.setBounds(300, 285, 450, 50);
        btnPlay.setBorderPainted(true);
        frame.add(btnPlay);

        btnHelp.setBounds(300, 350, 450, 50);
        btnHelp.setBorderPainted(true);
        frame.add(btnHelp);

        btnCredits.setBounds(300, 415, 450, 50);
        btnCredits.setBorderPainted(true);
        frame.add(btnCredits);

        btnExit.setBounds(300, 480, 450, 50);
        btnExit.setBorderPainted(true);
        frame.add(btnExit);

        Background background = new Background();
        frame.add(background);

        frame.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("/windowIcon.png")));

        btnExit.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (btnExit.getClick()) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }



}
```

Comment: Why are you extending JButton but not using any of its behaviors? Your overrides don't make sense. Please explain what you're trying to do with this code.

Comment: Also, a MouseListener won't work if you don't add it to anything. No where in the code above is there `addMouseListener(...)` called on any component.

Comment: I extend the Button class because i want to add mouse events there. In futute i'll work on custom button.

Comment: But there are much better ways of adding mouse events by using the functionality that JButton already has.

Comment: I have added action listener to button in my code

Comment: But as per my second comment above, you never added a MouseListener to anything. I'm not talking about ActionListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementing a MouseListener interface does not make the class use the MouseListener.

In your case you have to add the MouseListener to your Button:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#addMouseListener(java.awt.event.MouseListener)

```
public Button(String text) {
    super(text);
    setFont(new Font(null, Font.BOLD, 30));
    setText(text);
    addMouseListener(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro. I forget to add this. Now it's working. :)))

Comment: One more thing bro. Can i change the Button Color without overriding the paintComponent(Graphics g) methood ?

Comment: Use setBackground or setForeground method to change the color.

Comment: @MD.NASHIDKAMAL Although this answer is right it is definitely not the way to go. For once the JButton already handles Mouse events and for second an button reacts on more than mouse events. Will you adopt all of this?

Comment: But i think this is the exact answer what i was expecting.

Comment: @MD.NASHIDKAMAL: your program design is not good. If you want to be notified of mouse clicks there are other better ways to do it than what you're doing. Also your use of `setBounds` will cause problems later and will make your GUI very rigid and hard to improve or debug.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use JButton Direct if You are Using developing code with Swing no need to create Button Class Its already persent in javax.swing..

use
import javax.swing.*;

JButton btnPlay = new JButton("Play");
JButton btnHelp = new JButton("Help");
JButton btnCredits = new JButton("Credits");
JButton btnExit = new JButton("Exit");

Instead of this code..

Button btnPlay = new Button("Play");
Button btnHelp = new Button("Help");
Button btnCredits = new Button("Credits")
public Button btnExit = new Button("Exit");
```

Comment: I'll make Custom button later. So i need to extends the class

Comment: @MD.NASHIDKAMA *"I'll make Custom button later."* then you should also add the inheritance later. First make it run, then derive it. BTW: **why** do you plan to create a custom button? Will it have a new *behavior* or just a new layout...

Comment: My codes works well now bro. I forget to add addMouseListener to that class. That was the main problem. Thanks for your idea.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: He appears to be very new to Java and to Swing and does not yet know how best to use the libraries.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: *"He appears to be very new to Java"* then it is even more important to push her along the right way...

Comment: @TimothyTruckle: I agree 100%

Comment: Yes bro. I'm new. It's true . :))

Comment: it seems I can't accept two answers.